# Filling HTML table automatically from JSON WITH expandable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I am a beginning programmer and I'm trying to make a dynamic HTML table that is automatically filled using the information from a JSON object.  The catch is, I also want these rows to expand when I click on them to show a graph beneath it.

**I can fill the table dynamically with the information from the JSON.

**I can make a table that has expandable and collapsible rows.

**Now I just don't know how to do them at the same time!!!  Is it even possible??  Please help!!!**

Here's the code that's got (I've tried combining them in every way I can think of.).  This function dynamically fills the table with information from my JSON.

```
    $(function() {
       $.each(theBlob, function(i, item) {
          var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
          $('<td>').text(item.timestamp),
          $('<td>').text(item.workload_run),
          $('<td>').text(item.val),
          $('<td>').text(item.target)).appendTo('#reportTable');
       });
    });
```

This function makes the rows start closed and they open when you click on it to reveal a picture below.  This only works if I actually make a table and fill it manually with my information.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.clickable').click(function () {
          $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
            if($(this).is('.clickable')) {
              return false;
            }
            $(this).toggle();
         });
      });

      $('.clickable').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if(!($(this).is('.clickable')))
        $(this).hide();
      });
    pic});
```

And here is the rest of the code in case it's helpful:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%
  }

  table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  p {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  th {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
  }

  tr {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
  }

  #header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
  }

  #footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;

  }

  .footer, .push {
    height: .1em;
  }

  img {
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body onLoad = "buildHtmlTable()">
<div id="header">
  <h1>Production Active Monitoring Report for </h1><h1 id="date1"></h1>
</div>
<br>

<!-- ********************************************************* -->
<!--BELOW THIS COMMENT ARE THE ROWS THAT EXPAND WHEN CLICKED ON-->
<!--********************************************************* -->    
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Endpoint</th>
    <th>Average</th>
    <th>50th Percentile</th>    
    <th>90th Percentile</th>
    <th>Daily 90th Min </th>
    <th>Daily 90th Max </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable">
    <td colspan="1">Booklet:Campaign</td> <!-- Endpoint -->
    <td>3.06</td> <!-- Average -->    
    <td>3.00</td> <!-- 50th Percentile -->
    <td>4.11</td> <!-- 90th Percentile -->
    <td>3.63</td> <!-- Minimum -->
    <td>10.76</td>  <!-- Maximum -->  
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="graphExample.jpg" alt="Daily 90th percentile view">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="clickable">
    <td>Booklet:RootPerson</td> <!-- Endpoint -->
    <td>4.26</td> <!-- Average -->    
    <td>4.12</td> <!-- 50th Percentile -->
    <td>6.11</td> <!-- 90th Percentile -->    
    <td>4.68</td> <!-- Minimum -->
    <td>13.71</td>  <!-- Maximum -->
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="graphExample.jpg" alt="Daily 90th percentile view">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="clickable">
    <td>Booklet:Temple</td> <!-- Endpoint -->
    <td>4.94</td> <!-- Average -->
    <td>4.62</td> <!-- 50th Percentile -->
    <td>8.05</td> <!-- 90th Percentile -->
    <td>7.44</td> <!-- Minimum -->
    <td>15.58</td>  <!-- Maximum -->
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="graphExample.jpg" alt="Daily 90th percentile view">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--********************************************************* --> 
<!--BENEATH THIS IS THE TABLE CALL FOR AN AUTOMATIC TABLE-->
<!--********************************************************* --> 
<table id="reportTable">
<th>Timestamp</th>
<th>Workload_run</th>
<th>Val</th>
<th>Target</th>
</table>

<div class="wrapper"></div>
<br>
<div id="footer" class="footer"></div>

<script>

/**************************************************************************
***************************************************************************
            A function that dynamically pulls data from JSON.
***************************************************************************
**************************************************************************/
$(function() {
    $.each(theBlob, function(i, item) {
        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.timestamp),
            $('<td>').text(item.workload_run),
            $('<td>').text(item.val),
            $('<td>').text(item.target)).appendTo('#reportTable');
       //document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = ($tr.wrap('<p>').html());
    });
});


/**************************************************************************
***************************************************************************
            THIS DOES THE DATE THAT APPEARS IN THE HEADER.
***************************************************************************
**************************************************************************/
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
month = month + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var day = date.getDate();

var dayStamp = month + " / " + day + " / " + year;
document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = dayStamp;


/**************************************************************************
***************************************************************************
THIS FUNCTION IS WHAT MAKES THE GRAPHS APPEAR AND START OUT NOT DISPLAYED.
***************************************************************************
**************************************************************************/
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickable').click(function () {
      $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if($(this).is('.clickable')) {
          return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle();
      });
    });

    $('.clickable').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
      if(!($(this).is('.clickable')))
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });


/**************************************************************************
***************************************************************************
                SMALL JSON THAT I HAVE BEEN PRACTICING WITH.
***************************************************************************
**************************************************************************/
var theBlob =  [
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-24T20: 51: 09+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100266,
            "val": 4.307,
            "target": null
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-24T21: 15: 13+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100272,
            "val": 4.478,
            "target": null
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-24T21: 30: 13+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100276,
            "val": 3.667,
            "target": null
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-25T11: 15: 12+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100469,
            "val": 2.558,
            "target": null
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-25T11: 30: 12+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100473,
            "val": 2.73,
            "target": null
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-04-25T11: 45: 11+00: 00",
            "workload_run": 100477,
            "val": 2.605,
            "target": null
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that your have your jQuery click event wired up only works on elements that exist in the DOM when the command gets parsed. What you need to take a look into is an overload of the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method that replaces the old method `.delegate()`.

Basically, instead of selecting on the `tr` rows, your main select is something that will always be on the page. In this case, you can use the `table` element.

```
$('table').on('click', '.clickable', function () {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if($(this).is('.clickable')) {
          return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly for the clicking and displaying what's after it, but how can I put the picture after (or "underneath") every row if I am pulling the data dynamically?

Comment: You can add those just like you are creating the rows dynamically as you build those rows up in your topmost function in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change your js to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").on (click, '.clickable', function () {
          $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function() {
            if($(this).is('.clickable')) {
              return false;
            }
            $(this).toggle();
         });
      });

      $('.clickable').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
        if(!($(this).is('.clickable')))
        $(this).hide();
      });
    pic});
```

You need to atach the event to an existing object (body in this case). Check http://api.jquery.com/on/